# Как вытащить запрос с файла php

Tags: mysql

Есть запрос ввида

```
$db->query( "SELECT " . PREFIX . "_rko_comments.id, " . PREFIX . "_rko_comments.rko_id, " . PREFIX . "_rko_comments.otziv, " . PREFIX . "_rko_comments.tit_otziv, ". PREFIX . "_rko_comments.otziv, " . PREFIX . "_rko_comments.name_otziv, " . PREFIX . "_rko_comments.date, " . PREFIX . "_rko_comments.author, " . PREFIX . "_rko_comments.text, " . PREFIX . "_rko_post.title, " . PREFIX . "_rko_post.date as newsdate, " . PREFIX . "_rko_post.category FROM " . PREFIX . "_rko_comments LEFT JOIN " . PREFIX . "_rko_post ON " . PREFIX . "_rko_comments.rko_id=" . PREFIX . "_rko_post.id WHERE " . PREFIX . "_rko_comments.approve = '0' ORDER BY " . PREFIX . "_rko_comments.date DESC" );
```

Как привести его в вид запроса sql и сделать выполнение в базе

Comment: Если грубо перевести на русский - префикс это приставка в слове названия таблиц. Посмотри в базе названия. Они все начинаются на одно и то же слово. И в запросе просто замени

Answer (score 1, accepted):

За место слова "PREFIX" нужно вставить префикс таблиц
Например: dle_post - "dle" это префикс.

```
SELECT PREFIX_rko_comments.id, PREFIX_rko_comments.rko_id, PREFIX_rko_comments.otziv, PREFIX_rko_comments.tit_otziv, PREFIX_rko_comments.otziv, PREFIX_rko_comments.name_otziv, PREFIX_rko_comments.date, PREFIX_rko_comments.author, PREFIX_rko_comments.text, PREFIX_rko_post.title, PREFIX_rko_post.date as newsdate, PREFIX_rko_post.category FROM PREFIX_rko_comments LEFT JOIN PREFIX_rko_post ON PREFIX_rko_comments.rko_id= PREFIX_rko_post.id WHERE PREFIX_rko_comments.approve = '0' ORDER BY PREFIX_rko_comments.date DESC
```